# Given equation of one side and opposite point, find the equation of the other two sides of triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The vertex of an equilateral triangle is (**2**,**3**). The equation to the opposite side is **x+y=2**. Find the equation to the other two sides.

[Click here for Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ducqC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line $x + y = 2$ is $-1$ which forms a 45-degree angle with the x-axis. Therefore, the slopes of the other two sides must be $\tan{75°}$ and $\tan{15°}$. (Sorry for the atrocious drawing, but you get the idea)

[image]

Because the lines go through the point $(2,3)$, their line equations must be:

$$
y-3=\tan{75°}(x - 2)\\
y-3=\tan{15°}(x - 2)
$$

Comment: You drew $y+x=-2$ instead of $+2$ haha (I know it doesn't make a difference, al that matters is the slope). +1 anyway, the 'atrocious' drawing is quite useful

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that. But the point still holds. The line will cross 2 on the y-axis instead of -2. Thanks.